# Convert List to Rows

Tags: python, list

What is an efficient way to convert a list into separate elements in python?

I have a dataset that looks like this;

```
['StudentA','80','94','93']
['StudentB','93','94']
```

I would like to reshape the data so that each student/score has its own row;

```
['StudentA','80']
['StudentA','94']
etc...
```

Comment: Your dataset already has multiple rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Will the student name always be the first element of the list?

Comment: Is there a possibility that the set could look like this?
``['80','StudentA','94','93']``

Comment: Apologies. Student will always be first element, however each will not have a uniform set of scores associated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension, like this:

```
data = ['StudentA','80','94','93']
res = [[data[0], x] for x in data[1:]]
```

This sets `res` to `[['StudentA', '80'], ['StudentA', '94'], ['StudentA', '93']]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    c=['StudentA','80','94','93']

    d=[[c[0], p] for p in c[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were a list (`all_students`) containing each of these lines, you could do what you want, by doing :

```
result = []
for student in all_students:
    student_name = student[0]
    result.extend([[student_name, value] for value in student[1:]]
print(result)
```

Comment: You missed out a 't' at `sudent[1:]`; you might want to correct that so your example runs without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Couple **student** with it's respective **data** using a `dictionary`.

```
def to_dict(l):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        key = i[0]
        value = i[1:]
        d[key] = value
    return d
```

**Sample output:**

```
l = [['studentA', 90, 90],['studentB', 78, 40]]
print to_dict(l)
>>> {'studentB': [78, 40], 'studentA': [90, 90]}
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    for i in value:
        print key, i
>>> studentB 78
>>> studentB 40
>>> studentA 90
>>> studentA 90
```

Answer (score 0):

This dict comprehension will group you data by student name:

```
d = {x[0]: x[1:] for x in dataset}
```

i.e.:

```
>>> d
{'StudentA': ['80', '94', '93'], 'StudentB': ['93', '94']}
```

from which you can extract individual pairs with a nested for loop or list comprehension:

```
>>> [(k, w) for k, v in d.items() for w in v]
[('StudentA', '80'), ('StudentA', '94'), ('StudentA', '93'), ('StudentB', '93'), ('StudentB', '94')]
```